# Unable to execute JQuery into my Andro App, but the same executes in Chrome

Tags: javascript, android, html

Here I am making a simple App which should produce the output similar to this  --->

Visit http://i43.tinypic.com/2j8mrl.jpg

But the output doesn't appears to be so

I have installed Apache cordova, ant and set all my environment variables. 
I created the HelloWorld App using commandLine. I edited the  file in /asset/wwww folder
 And following is the code for index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
< title>PhoneGap Demo</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script

</head>
<body>

<div data-role="page" id="main">
<div data-role="header">
<h1>PhoneGap Demo</h1>
</div>
<div data-role="content">
Hello, this is JQuery Mobile running in Apache Cordova
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Can you please tell me why is this happening..

Comment: for a phonegap app it is always a good idea to include scripts and css files in the www folder instead of including it from the web.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you forgot to add cordova.js file to your html,
also you have to update your access policy to allow all urls, update your config.xml file with the following code:

```
<access origin="*" />
```

Comment: adding cordova.js make no changes. Error still persists.

Comment: Where do I find config.xml. Can't find in current directory of project

Comment: you can find it under www/config.xml